# Update with Looping SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, loops

I want to update Result row 1 = 15, row 2 = 5, row 3 = 30 with Looping:

[image]

Comment: Im sorry, i missed, I want to update with Looping

Comment: *"I want to update with Looping"* ***Why?*** You're writing SQL, not C#. Use a set-based approach.

Comment: because I want to see the ceiling topup Plafond, group by ID And Date

Comment: I don't follow what that means, but that still doesn't explain why. Like i said, you're writing SQL, which is a Query Language, not a programming language. Query Languages perform *very* poorly at iterative tasks and excel at set-based tasks (the opposite to Programming languages). If you think you want a loop, you're very thinking programmatically, not set-based; you have the wrong mind set. There are very few cases when you need a loop in SQL, and this is certainly not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `JOIN` :

```
UPDATE t1
     SET t1.Result = t.Result
FROM ( VALUES (1, 15), (2, 5), (3, 30)
     ) t(C,Result) INNER JOIN
     table t1
     on t1.c = t.c;
```

Comment: Thanks in Advance, How can I update with Looping

Comment: @YPG. . . `JOIN` will be best approach comparative to looping. So, why you want looping here for such simple approach.

Comment: because I want to see the ceiling topup Plafond, group by ID And Date. in my table has many ID. 
I made C to sort from the smallest ceiling